# how to create button displays image file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a webpage and I'm still learning HTML/CSS/Javascript. I'm trying to create a button such that it displays a random image file from my computer or database, but I'm not sure how to go about writing it. Here's my code:

```js
function display() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("img").src = "img_1.jpg";
}
```

```html
<button class="popup" onclick="display()">ITERATION.
  <span class="popupimg" id="img">img_1.jpg</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/800rksez/

Answer (score 2):

This, should be an img tag :)

```
<span class="popupimg" id="img">img_1.jpg</span>
```

like that:

```
<img src="img_1.jpg" id="img" />
```

Also, it doesnt have to be inside the button.
Your code should look something like

```
<button class="popup" onclick="display()">ITERATION.</button>
<img src="img_1.jpg" id="img" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `<img>`instead of a `<span>` if you want to display a image.

```js
function display() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("img").src = "img_1.jpg";
}
```

```html
<button class="popup" onclick="display()"><!-- What is this ? => ITERATION. -->
    <img id="img" src="">
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like following. But you should checkout jQuery too.

```js
function display(imagepath) {
  var img = document.getElementById("img");
  img.src = imagepath;
  img.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<img src='' style='display:none' id='img' width='120'>
<button class="popup" onclick="display('https://i.imgur.com/avAMfAu.jpg')">Show Image</button>
```

See example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pLd7jxam/)